# PHP install error in debian 8

Tags: php, debian, package

I am writing an ansible script for setting up server in debian 8

I need to install (php5-ming) (php5-ps) in Debian 8 but i get an error. How i can fix this?

Comment: If you want, add some details about "error" is so hard without details... :(

Comment: E: Unable to locate package php5-ming
E: Unable to locate package php5-ps

Comment: presumes you used apt, if yes, you added ppa repositories ?

Comment: I used apt-get install php5-ming, You can say me repository and how add